# How to replace Nan from column with float data in a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am trying to replace NAN from a dataframe column which is of float type.

```
> for i in range(len(tdf)):
>     if tdf['Counterfeit_Weight'][i] =='NaN': # also have tried with np.NaN
>         tdf.loc[i,"Counterfeit_Weight"]=p
```

I tried np.where, imputer class but nothing is working.

```
tdf.isnull().sum()
Medicine_ID               0
Counterfeit_Weight     1166
DistArea_ID               0
Active_Since              0
```

Plz Help

Comment: share your data with us, e.g df.head().to_dict(). Nan is normally replaced with fillna: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 1):

Following one line should work for you

```
tdf['Counterfeit_Weight'].fillna(p)
```